# DialogFragment with edittext doesn't lose keyboard after dismissed

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, dialogfragment

I have a custom DialogFragment with a single EditText and no buttons. After the text is entered into the edittext and I press "done", the keyboard stays visible upon returning to the host activity, even though the dialog is dismissed. It changes to a numerical keyboard, because the field in the host activity it focuses on is a numerical entry only `edittext` - but it may also focus on an edittext field I with normal text entry (and thus remain a normal keyboard) depending on where I left the cursor after I start the dialog fragment.

I have tried everything I could find (have googled and stackoverflowed a lot).

I based the dialogfragment on [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) code - it is very similar.

The problem is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997273/alertdialog-with-edittext-open-soft-keyboard-automatically-with-focus-on-editte), and I think the causes may be similar, but I have no buttons in my DialogFragment so I can't follow that solution though I don't think it matters I can follow it closely enough.

I have tried using `inputmethodmanager` as suggested there and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997273/alertdialog-with-edittext-open-soft-keyboard-automatically-with-focus-on-editte) to dismiss the keyboard, within the interface method (implemented in the host activity), and `onCreateView`, `onEditorAction` and `onDismiss` within the DialogFragment class. Also tried `getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);` (also using `SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN`) in the DialogFragment class methods. Did try `mEditText.clearFocus();` too in all the DF class methods to no avail.

Can anyone help at all? Is it to do with [David Chandler's code](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) I based mine on, or something I'm doing wrong specifically. All help most appreciated.

I include my DF class below in case anyone wants to look.

```
public class SetText extends DialogFragment {


public interface SetTextBoxDialogListener{
    void onFinishEnteringName(String name);
}


private EditText mEditText;

//Empty constructor req'd for dialogfragment.
public SetText(){

}


//Build view
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_set_the_text, container);
    mEditText =  (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
    getDialog().setTitle("Enter Name");


    //removing these 2 lines of code has no effect
    mEditText.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.VISIBLE);


    mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE==actionId){
                //return text to activity
                SetEnterNameDialogListener activity = (SetEnterNameDialogListener) getActivity();
                activity.onFinishEnteringName(mEditText.getText().toString());


                dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            //code for 2 lines below had now effect, even placed above dismiss
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        return false;
    }
});

return view;
}
}
```

Comment: You might try a solution similar to the following, but extend dimiss() instead of cancel() http://stackoverflow.com/a/23477289/1339200

Answer (score 2):

in the host activity tag in the manifest where you are returning from the DialogFragment use the following

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: I've already got that to prevent the keyboard appearing when I start the host activity I'm afraid.