# How to hide the onscreen keyboard when a DialogFragment is canceled by the setCanceledOnTouchOutside event

Tags: android, dialogfragment

If an edittext is currently focused and the user clicks outside of the DialogFragment; I want the on screen keyboard to disappear.  I can get it to work for when the DialogFragment is dismissed this way:

```
InputMethodManager imm;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflator, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
...}

@Override 
public void dismiss(){
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
    super.dismiss();
}
```

However, if I try the same thing for when it is canceled by touching outside of the dialogfragment, it will not work.  I am trying to do this by overriding onCancel like so:

```
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog){
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
    super.onCancel(dialog);
}
```

The function is called when the outside touch event happens, but the keyboard is not removed.

Comment: You need to override the `onDismiss()` method in your `DialogFragment` and hide the keyboard from there.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve the same problem by sub-classing the dialog and hiding the keyboard before the cancel code on the dialog was executed.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), getTheme()) {
        @Override public void cancel() {
            if (getActivity() != null && getView() != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            super.cancel();
        }

    };
    return dialog;
}
```

I tried many alternate approaches including using the DialogFragment's onCancel and onDimiss listeners to no avail.  I believe the issue is that the listeners are called asynchronously while the dismiss/cancel is handled synchronously; so by the time your listener is called to hide the keyboard, the window token no longer exists.

Comment: This gives the same issue, the cancel() is called, but the ime stays open.

Comment: This is the only one that helped.

Comment: Bravo! Note that `hideSoftInputFromWindow()` will still need to be issued elsewhere to cover normal `DialogFragment` termination.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get this to finally work... I needed to not use the widget for the keyboard... but use the currentfocus to get the windowtoken to remove the keyboard when a user selected something outside the dialog...

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    // make sure the keyboard goes away when the user selects something outside the view (cancelled outside)
    if( Utilities.isValidActivity(this.getActivity())) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        // not the search view but the current focus at this point
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);                          
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with the ime, this didn't work for me :(

Comment: This worked consistently for me. Thanks. Though I don't know what check you are doing with your Utilities class? What do you mean by isValidActivity?

Comment: what is isValidActivity?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by putting this in the AndroidManifest under the activity where I spawn the DialogFragment:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `onDismissListener` like this.

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I like the idea of this, but it does not work.  In fact, if the DialogFragment is dismissed by the touch outside event, the OnDissmissListener is ignored.  I know onCancel is called when the touch outside event happens, but hideSoftInputFromWindow does not do anything in this situation.

Comment: Which view calls the keyboard? Instead of `getView()` use the actual widget calling the keyboard to dismiss it.

Comment: I wasn't using the actual widget because their are multiple edittext widgets available on the screen.  However, I chose one to try out your suggestion, and it still does not work.

Comment: In fact, the onDismissListener is skipped altogether.  

Here is what I added inside of onCreateView of the DialogFragment:

this.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0){
        dismiss();
    }
});

This listener is not called when the setCanceledOnTouchOutside even happens.