# Hide to show and hide keyboard in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

In my dialog fragment, I am able to show the keyboard using

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT STATE_VISIBLE);
```

but I am not able to hide it on `dismiss`.

I've tried

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

and

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

neither of which work.

I've also tried showing and hiding the keyboard using

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

and

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

but these are not able to show or hide the keyboard.

```
 public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
    {
        @Nullable @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_input_dialog, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);

            final EditText editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.input);
            // this line below is able to show the keyboard 
            getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE); 
            Button add = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
            add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    // other code not shown
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
            Button cancel = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
            cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            //this line below does NOT work, it does not hide the keyboard
            getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            super.onDismiss(dialog);
        }
    }
```

**Note**: I have read these stackoverflow posts and have tried the proposed solutions to no avail:

1. [How to hide the onscreen keyboard when a DialogFragment is canceled by the setCanceledOnTouchOutside event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269466/how-to-hide-the-onscreen-keyboard-when-a-dialogfragment-is-canceled-by-the-setca)
2. [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The solution turned out to a combination of the following. To show the keyboard in a DialogFragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        editText.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                editText.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm =
                    (InputMethodManager)editText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm != null)
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
        });
    }
```

To hide it, use the solution above by @Shekhar

```
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        InputMethodManager imm =
            (InputMethodManager)editText.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm.isActive())
            imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }
```

Comment: Finally! It was getting the context from the edittext that I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes, when I show and dismiss dialog quickly, keyboard remains visible. Any ideas?

Comment: It is realy important to place it in onDismiss. E.g. by onStop it does not work, how ever

Comment: Interestingly, the `imm.showSoftInput(editText,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)` doesn't work if not called within `post{}`, but why?

Answer (score 6):

Hiding keyboard in a View inside DialogFragment:

```
public static void hideKeyboardInAndroidFragment(View view){
        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Hiding the Keyboard use this:

```
 private void hideKeyboard() {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) _activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(_activity.getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted this, but this is not the full answer. This only answers part of the question (hiding). Note that this answer does not work to close the keyboard when the keyboard was opened using `            getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);` See my answer below for the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

for hide soft keyboard, you can use this method:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
        try {
            View windowToken = getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getDialog().getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow( windowToken.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: finally this one worked in dialogfragment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hide it in DialogFragment onDestroyView() method:

```
 View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view == null) view = new View(activity);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)     getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm == null) return;
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

maybe work.

Answer (score 0):

I had extension for fragment, but didn't work with dialog fragment. This extension works for both (not tested much tho)

```
/**
 * If no window token is found, keyboard is checked using reflection to know if keyboard visibility toggle is needed
 *
 * @param useReflection - whether to use reflection in case of no window token or not
 */
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard(context: Context = App.instance, useReflection: Boolean = true) {
    val windowToken = view?.rootView?.windowToken
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    windowToken?.let {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
    } ?: run {
        if (useReflection) {
            try {
                if (getKeyboardHeight(imm) > 0) {
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
                }
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                Timber.e(exception)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun getKeyboardHeight(imm: InputMethodManager): Int = InputMethodManager::class.java.getMethod("getInputMethodWindowVisibleHeight").invoke(imm) as Int
```

Edit: toggle opened keyboard if it was closed before, I use reflection to get keyboard's height, which is not best solution, but works

Answer (score 0):

I found only one fully working approach if you want to show keyboard when dialog is shown and hide keyboard when dialog is dismissed

```
<style name="InputDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysVisible</item>
</style>
```

And then you should use the theme above inside your DialogFragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.InputDialog)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Kotil Extension function for DialogFragment hide keyboard

```
 use : hideKeyboard(view)
```

> ```
> fun DialogFragment.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
>     val imm =view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
>     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
> }
> ```