# Android animate edittext up on click

Tags: android

I have put ten edit text in scroll view when i click on edit text my keyboard appear. What i want when i click on edit text one its automatically show the edit text two which is right below the edit text one. I have used 
               android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
but none of them giving me the desired result and i think by doing this way i cannot acheive this.
Right Now I have to scroll manually or click on the next button. How to achieve this automatically as i have seen this functionality in many of the apps?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only shift the entire layout. You can, however, create a dialog and shift it. Try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997273/alertdialog-with-edittext-open-soft-keyboard-automatically-with-focus-on-editte

Comment: this is not the answer i am looking for as i told you i want automitacally visible the another edittext when i click on edittext which is right above.

Comment: Hard to understand what you are trying to do based on your question and the little information provided. Likely the reason for the downvotes. Are you saying when you click in edit text one you want it to focus edit text two?

Comment: first of all sorry for my little explanation , what i want is suppose we have three edit text named edittext_one ,edittext_two, edittext_three . I have put these edittext in scrollview. These edittext is clearly visible on the screen until my keyboard is not open. Now i click on edittext_one which is at the top and my keyboard appears and its hides my edittext_two and edittext_three. so i want to go edittext_two just little bit up so that user can see it same is happen with edittext_three i means when user click on edittext_two edittext_three slight move up so user can see it.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, within the "activity" declaration for the Activity you need to resize, add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

If it doesn't work with your ScrollView you may need to implement a simple ListView.