# EditText field in AlertDialog not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I'm new to android, trying to build a simple app involving some simple data input and management. When I follow the guide [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-prompt-user-input-dialog-example/), which ask for user input through an alert dialog. Everything works fine except that, after the AlertDialog appears, the `EditText` field does not have an input cursor displayed, and it won't display/update the text I typed. However, I can obtain the text string I typed in correctly after I pressed the 'OK' button in the alert dialog. Here is the xml file and code involving that dialog:

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type Your Message : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/grade_in"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</EditText>
```

code:

```
Button grade_in = button;

  grade_in.setTag(tag);
  grade_in.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View btn) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity.getApplicationContext());
            View prompt_grade_in = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grade_in, null);

            final EditText input_field = (EditText)prompt_grade_in.findViewById(R.id.grade_in);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

            alertBuilder.setView(prompt_grade_in);

            alertBuilder.setCancelable(true)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", 
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        Log.v(null, input_field.getText().toString());

                                    }
                                })

                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", 
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.cancel();

                                    }
                        })

                        .setMessage("Grade for the course:");

            AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
  });
```

I tried adding a TextWatcher but it does not help. Is the version the source of this problem? Because I think I pretty much followed the guide except that I've made some minor changes. Thanks for helping!

p.s. the page containing the button invoke the input dialog is a fragment.

**UPDATE:**
The fragment containing the button consists of an `ExpandableListView`, which is implemented according to this [guide](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listfragments) (part 15). And the above code implementing the alert dialog is in a custom adapter class, which create the group item in the list, inside the following function:

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_group, null);
}

CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

course courses = (course) getGroup(groupPosition);

((CheckedTextView) checkedTextView).setText(courses.code + " - " + courses.title);
((CheckedTextView) checkedTextView).setChecked(isExpanded);

String tag = courses.code + " - " + courses.title;

CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_course);
checkbox.setChecked(sharedPref.getBoolean(tag, false));
setBoxListener(checkbox, tag);

Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grade_button);
setBtnListener(button, tag);

return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/12998922/28557

Comment: Just tried, but problem persists. I think the creator in that topic is dealing with some problem with input method/keyboard?

Comment: Try  `input_field.requestFocus();`  after `alert.show();`

Comment: Identified and fixed by my friend, turns out that it is a minor mistake in:

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity.getApplicationContext());

Instead it should be:

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

And I thought I am using activity right from the beginning. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified and fixed by my friend, turns out that it is a minor mistake in:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity.getApplicationContext());
```

Instead it should be:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
```

And I thought I am using activity right from the beginning. :(

Answer (score 1):

try to set  `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"` to your `EditText` for input Cursor Display

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the problem still persists. :(

Comment: The EditText field disappear (not displayed) if cursorVisible and background attributes are set to true and @null respectively.

Comment: @alanlo post some more code for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Import first.

if you are using `androidx.`
use:

> androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog

instead of

> import android.app.AlertDialog;

check input type

Answer (score 0):

replace your EditText code in xml with the following code. The following code contains  tag, which gets the focus in the EditText. Hope this will solve your issue.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/grade_in"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Call the soft keyboard before you create the AlertDialog.

```
alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too... In my case : I Used custom dialog, extends  `DialogFragment` / `AppCompatDialogFragment`  and EdidText inside my `dialog_custom.xml`;

I add following code inside onStart in my dialog class and worked fine the `EditText`:

```
override fun onStart() {
     super.onStart()
     dialog!!.window!!.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM)
}
```