# Set Request Focus to Edittext In Adapter Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

i am trying to set request focus to edittext of my alertdialog box but it didnt show me the keyboard
i have added the code follow. I have also set the requestFocus() to the edittext 
But it didnt display anything.

```
 mHolder.txt_lName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getmenuname = firstName.get(pos);
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Select Quantity");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Quantity");
                    final EditText input = new EditText(mContext);
                    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                    input.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));
                    input.requestFocus();
                    input.setFocusable(true);
                    int maxLength = 4;
                    InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
                    fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);

                    input.setFilters(fArray);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    alertDialog.setView(input);
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                  /*  int a = Integer.parseInt(mHolder.txt_lName.getText().toString());
                                    int b = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
                                    //int c = Integer.parseInt(taxEditText.getText().toString().toTrim());
                                    int result = a + b ;*/

                                    updatedquantity = input.getText().toString();
                                    if (updatedquantity.matches("")) {
                                        //Toast.makeText(mContext, "You did not enter a quantitiy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        input.setError("You did not enter a quantitiy");

                                        return;
                                    } else {
                                        //mHolder.txt_lName.setText(updatedquantity);
                                        getupdateQuantity(getmenuname);
                                        ((DisplayActivity) mContext).displayData();
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    alertDialog.show();

                }

            });

        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        //mHolder.txt_id.setText(id.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_fName.setText(firstName.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_lName.setText(lastName.get(pos));
        return child;
    }
```

Comment: [Focus an EditText in an AlertDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997273/alertdialog-with-edittext-open-soft-keyboard-automatically-with-focus-on-editte )

Answer (score 4):

> Create a custom dialog like this

```
 private void ShowDialog() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.you_dialog_layout, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilderUserInput.setView(mView);
        final AlertDialog alertDialogAndroid = alertDialogBuilderUserInput.create();
        alertDialogAndroid.show();
        final EditText edt_qty = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.edt_subject);
        Button cvSubmit = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.cvSubmit);

        cvSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(edt_subject.getText().length()==0)
                {
                    edt_qty.requestFocus();
                    edt_qty.setError("You did not enter a quantitiy");

                } else {
                //code
                }

            }
        });
    }

mHolder.txt_lName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ShowDialog();
        }
    });
```