# android anko alert custom layout currentFocus

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, anko

I have a alert view with custom layout which contains EditText

```
activity.alert {
        var quantityEt: EditText? = null

        customView {
            linearLayout {
                orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL

                quantityEt = editText {}

                quantityEt!!.requestFocus()
                Log.e("LOL", ac.window.currentFocus.toString())
            }
        }
    }.show()
```

then I request focus to this edit text. However, `activity.window.currentFocus` outputs that the currentFocus android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.

I need the currentFocus to be EditText. I also tried to tap it to request focus, but still got RecyclerView.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997273/alertdialog-with-edittext-open-soft-keyboard-automatically-with-focus-on-editte

Comment: @Rahul, it is not the same. I create EditText in alert view as part of custom view. In this question they created edit text outside.